# Can't manage to connect my virtual machine to the internet

Tags: vmware-player, windows-2003-webserver

I have a windows server 2003 as the guest in VMware player and windows 7 enterprise as the host. I'm trying to connect to the inernet from my guest and i can't. In my VMware player virtual machine settings my network addapter is set to NAT but i can't get it to work.My host is in the work LAn and connected to the internet through it. Could this have something to do with it not working properly? Do I have to perform some special setup?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be caused by:

- You're NATting to the wrong host's network interface in the VM's option.
- Your VM's NIC DNS configuration is wrong. To verify this issue, try to PING the host's NIC from the VM.